# Increment UIStepper Value based on minute, hour, day etc. SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uistepper

I am currently trying to increment a uistepper and change its value based on its current value. The uistepper is supposed to act as a time keeper. It increments by 5 minutes until it reaches 60 minutes, where it then increments by 60 minutes. Once it reaches 120 minutes, I want the stepper to increment by 1440 minutes which is 1 day. My code is having issues, however, and another problem I'm running into is decrementing the stepper so that you can go from a day back down to an hour and then back down to minutes.

This is my code right now:

```
func stepperValueChanged(stepper: UIStepper) {
    var value = Int(stepper.value)
    stepper.minimumValue = 0
    if (stepper.value != 0 && stepper.value <= 60) {
        stepper.stepValue = 5
        stepper.value -= 5
        stepper.value += 5
        value = Int(stepper.value)
        reminderSubLabel.text = "\(value) minutes before"
        if stepper.value == 60 {
        reminderSubLabel.text = "\(value / 60) hour before"
        }
    } else if stepper.value >= 60 && stepper.value <= 180 {
        if stepper.value == 60 {
            reminderSubLabel.text = "\(value / 60) hour before"
            stepper.value -= 5
            stepper.value += 60
        } else {
        //stepper.value = 120
        value = Int(stepper.value / 60)
        stepper.stepValue = 60
        stepper.value -= 60
        stepper.value += 60
        reminderSubLabel.text = "\(value) hours before"
        }
        if stepper.value == 120 {
            stepper.value = 1440
            stepper.value -= 1320
            stepper.value += 1440
            //stepper.stepValue = 1320
        }
    }
    if stepper.value == 0 {
        stepper.stepValue = 5
        stepper.value = 0
        reminderSubLabel.text = "At the time of the event"

    }
    stepper.minimumValue = 0
    stepper.maximumValue = 20160
    print("\(stepper.value)")
}
```

Comment: You have a serious design issue.

Comment: You have "stepper.value = 5" and in the next line "stepper.value = 0". You do this also in other places. What is the purpose of that? why assigning the stepper value to 5 and then to 0?

Comment: @ElTomato what would your approach be? I understand the code is messy and repetitive and I'm just looking for help

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I'm not quite sure I set the value to 5 then 0, but I do see that I set the stepValue to 5 and then then the value to 0. The reason I do this is so that the value of the stepper resets to 0 and the stepValue resets to 5 when it reaches its minimum value

Comment: "It increments by 5 minutes until it reaches 60 minutes, where it then increments by 60 minutes . Once it reaches 120 minutes, I want the stepper to increment by 1440 minutes which is 1 day."  Don't do that.  That's what I mean by a design issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not bind to the value property of UIStepper. Try use sort of abstraction where value of stepper is x and value you need in minutes is y. All you need is to implement y = f(x) in stepperValueChanged(stepper:). It's pretty simple if step is 1.

```
var minutes = 0

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ stepper: UIStepper) {
    let value = Int(stepper.value)
    var minutes = 0
    for step in 0..<value {
        if step <= 11 {
            minutes += 5
        } else if step <= 12 {
            minutes += 60
        } else {
            minutes += 1440
        }
    }
    self.minutes = minutes
}
```